# Tar problem with apache commons compress

Tags: java, apache-commons, tar, compression

I'm having a hard time trying to tar some files using the compress library.

My code is the following, and is taken from the commons.compress wiki exemples :

```
    private static File createTarFile(String[] filePaths, String saveAs) throws Exception{

    File tarFile = new File(saveAs);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tarFile);

    TarArchiveOutputStream aos = (TarArchiveOutputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveOutputStream("tar", out);

    for(String filePath : filePaths){
        File file = new File(filePath);
        TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry(file);
        entry.setSize(file.length());
        aos.putArchiveEntry(entry);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), aos);
        aos.closeArchiveEntry();
    }
    aos.finish();
    out.close();


    return tarFile;
}
```

There is no error during the process, but when I try to untar the file, I got the following :

```
XXXX:XXXX /home/XXXX$ tar -xf typeCommandes.tar
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Also, the archive IS slighty smaller in size than the original file, which isnt normal for a tar, so there DO is a problem...

```
-rw-r--r--  1 XXXX nobody 12902400 Jan 14 17:11 typeCommandes.tar
-rw-r--r--  1 XXXX nobody 12901888 Jan 14 17:16 typeCommandes.csv
```

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing the `TarArchiveOutputStream`.  Add `aos.close()` after `aos.finish()`

Answer (score 2):

Small correction to the code above.
It does not close input stream, while Apache lib assumes that stream is managed by calling client.
See the fix below (put this code after the line 'aos.putArchiveEntry(entry)') :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileForPuttingIntoTar);
IOUtils.copy(fis, aos);
fis.close();
aos.closeArchiveEntry();
```

Answer (score 0):

the example here -> http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html uses the method *putNextEntry(entry)* which you seem to omit.

Answer (score 0):

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997869/make-tar-file-by-java/38489253#38489253)

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream;

public class TarUpdater {

        private static final int buffersize = 8048;

        public static void updateFile(File tarFile, File[] flist) throws IOException {
            // get a temp file
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tarFile.getName(), null);
            // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing tar to it.
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                tempFile.delete();
            }

            if (!tarFile.exists()) {
                tarFile.createNewFile();
            }

            boolean renameOk = tarFile.renameTo(tempFile);
            if (!renameOk) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "could not rename the file " + tarFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[buffersize];

            TarArchiveInputStream tin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));

            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(tarFile.toPath()));
            TarArchiveOutputStream tos = new TarArchiveOutputStream(outputStream);
            tos.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_POSIX);

            //read  from previous  version of  tar  file
            ArchiveEntry entry = tin.getNextEntry();
            while (entry != null) {//previous  file  have entries
                String name = entry.getName();
                boolean notInFiles = true;
                for (File f : flist) {
                    if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                        notInFiles = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (notInFiles) {
                    // Add TAR entry to output stream.
                    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                        tos.putArchiveEntry(new TarArchiveEntry(name));
                        // Transfer bytes from the TAR file to the output file
                        int len;
                        while ((len = tin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            tos.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                    }
                }
                entry = tin.getNextEntry();
            }
            // Close the streams
            tin.close();//finished  reading existing entries 
            // Compress new files

            for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
                if (flist[i].isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(flist[i]);
                TarArchiveEntry te = new TarArchiveEntry(flist[i],flist[i].getName());
                //te.setSize(flist[i].length());
                tos.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU);
                tos.setBigNumberMode(2);
                tos.putArchiveEntry(te); // Add TAR entry to output stream.

                // Transfer bytes from the file to the TAR file
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = fis.read(buf, 0, buffersize)) != -1) {
                    tos.write(buf, 0, count);
                }
                tos.closeArchiveEntry();
                fis.close();
            }
            // Complete the TAR file
            tos.close();
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }
```