# Create a TAR File (tarball) using Coldfusion\Java on a windows server

Tags: java, coldfusion, compression, tar

I need to create a TAR file containing multiple files on a windows server using Coldfusion\Java. I have found lots of examples of unpacking them, but very little on creating them. I found this example of using gzip to add some text to a file and that works, but I need to add files. I'm also not 100% sure that gzip is the same thing as building a tarball. This project was assigned to me with a very short turn-around and I'm spinning my wheels so any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated:

Win Server 2012,
ColdFusion 10,
Java Version 1.7.0_15

```
    <cfset lineBreak = chr(13) & chr(10) />
<!--- open the sitemap file --->
<cfset tarFilePath = "#application.imageingFolder#DTSimages\Pending\tiff.gz" />
#tarFilePath#
<!--- create streams --->
<cfset outputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").Init(
            CreateObject("java","java.io.File").Init(tarFilePath)) />
<cfset gzipStream = CreateObject("java", "java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream").Init(outputStream) />
<cfsavecontent variable="siteMapHeader"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
    xmlns:video="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset siteMapFooter = "</urlset>" />
<cfset gzipStream.write(ToString(siteMapHeader).GetBytes()) />

<cfset gzipStream.close() />
<cfset outputStream.close() />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though [often used together](https://fileinfo.com/extension/tar.gz), tar and gzip are different things. From [ZIP vs. GZIP](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516125635/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html):

> ... The tar command is used to create an archive (not
> compressed) and another program (gzip or compress) is used to compress
> the archive.

A simple option is to install [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) (which supports tar and gzip) and invoke it from [cfexecute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html) with the appropriate arguments. To create a TAR file (not compressed):

```
<!--- 
   "a" - add files to archive 
   "t" - Type of archive 
   output .tar file 
   space separated list of files to add 
--->
<cfexecute name="c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    arguments=" a -ttar c:\path\myarchive.tar c:\path\file1.xlsx c:\temp\otherfile.txt"
    variable="output"
    errorVariable="error"
    timeout="60"    />

<cfoutput>
    output = #output#<br>
    error = #error#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

For java options, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997869/make-tar-file-by-java/6997984#6997984) mentions using the Apache Commons library for creating TAR files. It also happens to bundled with CF so it should work out of the box:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html

```
<cfscript>
    // Initialize TAR file to generate
    outputPath = "c:/temp/outputFile3.tar";
    os = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(outputPath);
    tar = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream").init(os);
    
    // Add an entry from a string
    someTextContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>....';
    binaryContent = charsetDecode(someTextContent, "utf-8");
    entry = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry").init("siteHeader.xml");
    entry.setSize(arrayLen(binaryContent));
    tar.putArchiveEntry(entry);
    tar.write(binaryContent);
    tar.closeArchiveEntry();
    
    // Create an entry from a file
    inputFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("c:/path/someImage.jpg");
    entry = tar.createArchiveEntry(inputFile, "myImage.jpg");
    tar.putArchiveEntry(entry);
    tar.write(FileReadBinary(inputFile));
    tar.closeArchiveEntry();

    // Close TAR file
    tar.flush();
    tar.close();
</cfscript>
```

See the documentation for more details: [Apache Commons - The TAR package](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/tar.html)

**NB:** If you are archiving large files, look into buffering. For the basic concept, see [Code Sample 3: Zip.java](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516125635/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html). Ignore the fact that it is for Zip files. The basic concept is the same, only the classes differ.

Comment: That worked! I had been trying jTar, but wasn't having much luck and was about to try this. I am getting a wierd error when I open the TAR file in 7-zip:

Comment: The error is "There are data after end of archive". I'm not sure what that is about.

Comment: Using which example? In my (brief) tests, both opened without error in 7zip for me.

Comment: I only used the create an entry from file portion and commented out the entry from string. I also repeated the entry from file and added two tiff files. I get the same error from 7-zip each time, but the file still opens in 7-zip and I can extract the files without an issue. This discussion talks about the issue, but it seem inconsequential:

Comment: The discussion referenced above end by sating that they fixed the issue by going from commons 1.0 to 1.9. I confirmed that CF10 used 1.0, but I'm not sure I should try replacing that with another version.

Comment: This is working but I also need to place the files in the tar using a directory structure. How do I create or specify a path?

Comment: I figured it out, I just add it before the filename:
entry = tar.createArchiveEntry(inputFile, "1234\TestImage.tiff");

Comment: *I confirmed that CF10 used 1.0...*  Ah, I tested with CF11 so that might explain it.  Since you are using CF10+, instead of overwriting the built in jars, try loading a newer version with [this.javaSettings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html). It is basically a rip of the JavaLoader.cfc, baked into the Application.cfc.