# How to store multiple files on a single file?

Tags: android, file, storage

I'm building an app that will let people store different file types (.txt, .jpg, .pdf, etc) in classes created by them, example:

Class Documents -> Add a .Doc -> Store.

This give people the ability to have it's personal files stored in a more organized way.

But I don't want to create a folder with the class name and save everything inside, what I want is to store all the files of the same class on a single file for easy handling.

Class Documents -> Add a .Doc -> Store on single file archive -> Read later.

I've been looking at storing everything as blobs on SQlite, but not sure how reading times would affect the smoothness of app (some HD images can go up to 10MB and I need some previews, should I make thumbnails?). Should I use SQLite to store the files?.

When I was a child, I remember some games having multiple 3D objects inside of a single file.

I even see a guy talking about making a file with a filesystem within it to store multiple files.

Zip files look promising, but I don't want people going to SD card and extracting the files, or is there a way to encrypt or update the zip file with password?

So, what do you think is the best approach to store multiiple files on a single one? If helps you, I'm programming on Android Java.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Use a tar ball. I know there are very small c implementations floating around, you might be able to find a Java version.  Later, you can gzip if you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997869/make-tar-file-by-java

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jtar needs the "java.nio.file" package, but that's available for Android Oreo Api 26 and up only. I'm still looking for options, right now, the most easy option is ZIP files.