# I want to TAR a multiple files on JBOSS server in Eclipse using java

Tags: java, tar

I have tried multiple examples... But non will work for me
[Make tar file by Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997869/make-tar-file-by-java/63954965#63954965)
If I use above code, After reading the line  TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( dest ) ); it just come out of the method(i.e.After reading that line... it won't executed the code which are after to that. The Sequence directly gone to the finally block where that method called).

For another example, I used apache common compress Jar. In that case it won't execute the java class itself it exit from the FormBean class.

The files are fetched from the database and it will be in a CSV format and all the files are placed in an Array List.

```
fileNames = "Security.smod."+SYSDATE;
strSavePath = D\:\\CMSREPORT\\reportZip\\
tarFunction(fileList, strSavePath, fileNames);

//Example function 1
private String tarFunction(ArrayList fileList, String strSavePath, String outFileName) {
     int fileCountSize = fileList.size();
      // Output file stream
   FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream( strSavePath );

   // Create a TarOutputStream
   TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( dest ) );

   // Files to tar
   File[] filesToTar=new File[3];
for(int i=0; i<fileCountSize; i++)
{
   filesToTar[i]=new File((String) fileList.get(i);
  }

   for(File f:filesToTar){
      out.putNextEntry(new TarEntry(f, f.getName()));
      BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( f ));

      int count;
      byte data[] = new byte[2048];
      while((count = origin.read(data)) != -1) {
         out.write(data, 0, count);
      }

      out.flush();
      origin.close();
   }
}
```

For Example 2, I used apache.common.compress.1.2 as a jar.
In that case, It won't execute the java class, it exited from the FormBean class.

```
//Example function 2
private void tarFunc(){
        try{
             // Files to tar
             File resource1 = new File((String) fileList.get(0));
             File resource2 = new File((String) fileList.get(1));
             File resource3 = new File((String) fileList.get(2));
         // Output Stream - that will hold the physical TAR file 
        OutputStream tar_output = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileNames+".tar"));
       //  Create Archive Output Stream that attaches File Output Stream / and specifies TAR as type of compression 
        ArchiveOutputStream my_tar_ball = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveOutputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.TAR, tar_output);
       //  Create Archieve entry - write header information
        TarArchiveEntry tar_file = new TarArchiveEntry(resource1);
       //  length of the TAR file needs to be set using setSize method 
        tar_file.setSize(resource1.length());
        my_tar_ball.putArchiveEntry(tar_file);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(resource1), my_tar_ball);
       //  Close Archieve entry, write trailer information 
        my_tar_ball.closeArchiveEntry();
       //  Repeat steps for the next file that needs to be added to the TAR 
        tar_file = new TarArchiveEntry(resource2);
        tar_file.setSize(resource2.length());
        my_tar_ball.putArchiveEntry(tar_file);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(resource2), my_tar_ball);
       //  Close Archieve entry, write trailer information 
        my_tar_ball.closeArchiveEntry();
    tar_file = new TarArchiveEntry(resource3);
        tar_file.setSize(resource3.length());
        my_tar_ball.putArchiveEntry(tar_file);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(resource3), my_tar_ball);
       //  Close Archieve entry, write trailer information 
        my_tar_ball.closeArchiveEntry();
        my_tar_ball.finish(); 
        // Close output stream, our files are zipped 
        tar_output.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Anyone please help to solve this issue. Thank you:)

Comment: "it just come out of the method" what do you mean?

Comment: After reading that line... it won't executed the code which are after to that. The Sequence directly gone to the finally block where that method called.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and show your code.

Comment: Are you doing this in a try/catch/finally block? Or a try/finally block without a catch?

Comment: In a try/catch/finally block